# determine whether process has done execution in Java

Tags: java, process

I have this statement to execute `foo.exe`

`Process process = new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe","param1","param2").start();`

The execution sequence I expect is

1. Java calls `foo.exe`
2. Java on halt (wait for `foo.exe` finish)
3. `foo.exe` executes
4. `foo.exe` finished execution
5. Java continues

How can I do this ?

**Edit :** i tried `process.waitFor()`, it makes `foo.exe` forever stuck and wont terminate. i suspect that `foo.exe` cant executes to its completion.

And I don't really get why i got voted down. Sorry if this is a inappropriate question. I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add  p.waitFor();

```
Process p= new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe","param1","param2").start();
p.waitFor(); // this will wait till process finish
```

**edited -- as in question is edited**

> some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

Try This code :

```
 Process p= new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe","param1","param2").start();
    new Thread(new Reader(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
    new Thread(new Reader(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
    int returnCode = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);
```

Reader class

```
class Reader implements Runnable
{
public Reader (InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      istrm = istrm;
      ostrm = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
      try
      {
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          for (int length = 0; (length = istrm.read(buffer)) != -1; )
          {
              ostrm.write(buffer, 0, length);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  private final OutputStream ostrm;
  private final InputStream istrm;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried it and `foo.exe` wont execute to its completion.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try that?

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe","param1","param2").start();
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried it and `foo.exe` wont execute to its completion.

Comment: `int result = p.waitFor();`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to wait for it's termination, you can check if it was terminated by calling the [exitValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()), without blocking your current thread execution:

```
public static boolean hasTerminatedExecution(Process p) {
    try {
        p.exitValue();
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException exception) {
        return false; // exception thrown if process didn't terminated yet
    }
}
```